# Is my script secure to prevent email injection?

Tags: php

I have an email contact form that is PHP and very basic. I am concerned, however, that injections might be possible through it. So I was wondering if anyone with far superior PHP skills than myself would be willing to take a look and see if I have any gaps or vulnerabilities in my code that could be exploited. I very much appreciate any help with this.

PHP

```
<?php

$field_name = isset( $_POST['cf_name'] ) ? preg_replace( "/[^\.\-\' a-zA-Z0-9]/", "", $_POST['cf_name'] ) : "";
$field_email = isset( $_POST['cf_email'] ) ? preg_replace(  "/[^\.\-\_\@a-zA-Z0-9]/" , "", $_POST['cf_email'] ) : "";
$field_message = isset( $_POST['cf_message'] ) ? preg_replace( "/(From:|To:|BCC:|CC:|Subject:|Content-Type:)/", "", $_POST['cf_message'] ) : "";

$mail_to = 'admin@mywebsite.com';
$subject = 'New Contact for My Website from '.$field_name;

$body_message = 'From: '.$field_name."\n";
$body_message .= 'E-mail: '.$field_email."\n";
$body_message .= 'Message: '.$field_message;

$headers = 'From: '.$field_email."\r\n";
$headers .= 'Reply-To: '.$field_email."\r\n";

$mail_status = mail($mail_to, $subject, $body_message, $headers);

?>
```

For the brief moment I had this on Stack Overflow (before I was told that it should be here) the comment was made that I shouldn't be stripping characters out of emails. So... what should I do then? Is there a simple method to achieve the goal that I am missing? I am very new to this and just want to be as secure as possible.

Comment: Sanitizing input isn't really what you need (to some extent), what is more important is to properly escape your output. Take a look at the answers here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17103318/correct-way-to-sanitize-input-in-mysql-using-pdo/17103381#17103381

Comment: Michael, thank you so much for the link. I think I understand what is happening with the htmlspecialchars and how it is protecting my contact form. However, I am a little unsure as to where I would put it in my code. Would I want to eliminate the sanitizing script and just use htmlspecialchars or do I want to sanitize and then cancel the output? Thank you so much for your direction so far! I am new to the php side of things and especially to the security part (one of the most important parts) Thanks again!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Validate, but don't change user input

Don't change the value of a user input. Either accept or reject it, but don't try to guess what might be ment. Some examples:

The name could be `Søren Kierkegård`, which in many evironments will become `Sren Kierkegrd` due to your 'sanitation'.

An email address can be much more complicated than your test suggests. How about parenthesis, exclamation or question marks? [Read this for other thoughts about email validation with regular expressions](http://www.regular-expressions.info/email.html).

The message still could contain 'Bcc:' or 'Cc:'. Making the expression case insensitive will lead to the next problem: The sequence "People I met in Toronto: A, B, and C." would become "People I met in Toron A, B, and C."

### Escape your output instead

Header fields are restricted to a single line (each). So is the name of a person. In these cases, all whitespaces are equivalent (at least for non-malicious input), so replacing newlines and tabs with spaces does not alter the (meaning of the) content.

```
$name    = isset($_POST['cf_name']) ? $_POST['cf_name'] : '';
$email   = isset($_POST['cf_email']) ? $_POST['cf_email'] : '';
$message = isset($_POST['cf_message']) ? $_POST['cf_message'] : '';

$mail_status = sendMail($name, $email, $message);

function sendMail($name, $email, $message)
{
    // Whitespace pattern, icluding different masking methods
    $whitespace = '~(<CR>|<LF>|0x0A|%0A|0x0D|%0D|\\n|\\r|\s)+~i';

    $name = trim(preg_replace($whitespace, '', $name));
    if (empty($name)) {
        return false;
    }

    $email = trim(preg_replace($whitespace, ' ', $email));
    if (empty($email)) {
        return false;
    }

    $mail_to = 'admin@mywebsite.com';
    $subject = 'New Contact for My Website from ' . $name;

    $body =  "From: $name\n";
    $body .= "E-mail: $email\n";
    $body .= "Message: $message";

    $headers =  "From: $email\r\n";
    $headers .= "Reply-To: '$email\r\n";

    return mail($mail_to, $subject, $body, $headers);
}
```

Comment: nibra, thank you so much for the response and what you are explaining makes sense. Far too much potential to strip content that you don't necessarily want to strip. On the basis of what you have written here, it appears that you are just taking any malicious content and replacing it with whitespace, which in turn, escapes the output. So if I use this script (making the appropriate edits to the email and subject header) it should work correct? At least it appears that it should...

Comment: I think so, and I'd also use it without fear. But you never know for sure.

Comment: nibra, thanks again for your help. I implemented the script and I am not getting the messages delivered to the address that is entered. Let me give you the code that I have posting the information entered to the php.

Comment: `<form id="myForm" action="send_form_email.php" method="post">
      NAME<span>*</span><br>
      <input name="cf_name" type="text" size="32"><br>
      EMAIL<span>*</span><br>
      <input name="cf_email" type="text" size="32"><br>
      MESSAGE<span>*</span><br>
      <textarea name="cf_message" maxlength="1000" cols="30" rows="6" style="resize:none;"></textarea><br>
      <input type="submit" value="Send">
      <input type="reset" value="Clear">
</form>`

Comment: Also to note, I have a jQuery script that is validating the information to ensure that the fields are completed properly, but I don't think that should be interfering with the script since it isn't posting any data, but checking the data and popping up an alert.

Comment: What's in `$mail_status`?

Comment: Exactly as you scripted it `$mail_status = sendMail($name, $email, $message);`

Comment: So what's in `$mail_status`? Hint: `var_dump($mail_status);`

Comment: nibra, I tracked it down. :) the preg_replace of the $name variable was missing a second parentheses to close out the trim. It seems to be working just fine now. Thank you so much for your help.